# MySQL / PHP Outfile breaks lines incorrectly

Tags: php, into-outfile

As part of trying to automate some of my data as apposed to running it manually on a daily basis I have created a *.bat file that executes a PHP script. The script runs perfectly, however for some reason, and I'm not sure why there seem to be intervals of incorrect line breaks in the resulting CSV file.

When I used to run the script manually on MySQL Workbench the export worked correctly without the line breaks.

I have included a screenshot of the current (automated) result as an example, the rows highlighted in red were incorrectly "Line Broken".[image]
My Outfile Code is :

```
$sql11 = ("SELECT
            'STORE_CODE'
        ,   'OUTLET_NAME'
        ,   'CALL_CYCLE_DAY'
        ,   'RSM_DETAILS'
        ,   'ASM_DETAILS'
        ,   'FM_DETAILS'
        ,   'BSS_DETAILS'
        ,   'MEGA_REGION'
        ,   'REGION'
        ,   'SUB_REGION'
        ,   'MICRO_REGION'
        ,   'SEGMENT'
        ,   'BRAND'
        ,   'AVAILABILITY'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT
            store_code
        ,   outlet_name
        ,   call_cycle_day
        ,   CONCAT(rsm_number, ' | ' ,rsm_name)
        ,   CONCAT(asm_number, ' | ' ,asm_name)
        ,   CONCAT(fm_number, ' | ' ,fm_name)
        ,   CONCAT(bss_number, ' | ' ,bss_name)
        ,   mega_region
        ,   region
        ,   sub_region
        ,   micro_region
        ,   segment
        ,   brand
        ,   availability
    FROM
      metrics.availabilty
    INTO
      OUTFILE 'E:/Data/exports/DailyExports/Availability_".date('Ymd').".csv'
    FIELDS
      TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES
      TERMINATED BY '\n'
");
```

I have also tried it without using the CONCAT fields as well as saying           `TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`
but have the same kind of output on file. As mentioned earlier in the post, when running it directly / manually in MySQL Workbench the file also exports correctly.

Some other additional information is that the "SKU Available" / "SKU Not Available" Indicators are created using a CASE statement. And although not visible on the sample screen shot, the line break happens on both fields.

Comment: Try escaping \n on the second last line, i.e. \\n. When running that query in MySQL workbench, the escape sequence \n will be sent to the server, while when you run it from PHP, it'll be translated to an actual CHR 13. That might confuse end up confusing MySQL?

Comment: Tried doing \\n as suggested, but still getting the line break. I also tried \\r just to see the result and this added an additional row between each and every record.